# Jquery ui progress bar is not displayed in front of the other elements

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, jquery-ui, progress-bar

I'm using JQuery UI 1.8.20, asp.net 4.0, VS 2010 and

I have a problem displaying a progress bar in front of all other markup elements when loading data to populate some lists.

My html markup is basically this (splitDocumentProgressbar is the progress bar):

```
<div id="mainCategorizerContainer">
    <div id="uncategorizedArea" class="uncategorized-area">        
        <ul id="uncategorizedPagesList" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix uncategorized-document-pages-list-area uncategorizedPages">                   
        </ul>        
    </div>
    <div id="categorizedArea" class="categorized-area">
        <ul id="documentCategoryList" class="document-category-list-area ui-helper-reset">                                      
        </ul>
        <ul id="categorizedDocumentPagesList" class="categorized-document-pages-list-area ui-helper-reset" >                       
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="splitDocumentProgressbar" style="width: 20%;"></div>
    <div id="splitDocumentDialog"><span id="splitDocumentDialogContent"></span></div>
</div>
```

The javascript that populates one list and updates the progress bar (this code is in an external javascript file that I have written and this file is referenced in the aspx where the markup is defined):

```
var initializeUncategorizedPagesList = function (data) {
    var listItems = [];

    var progressBarSteps = data.DocumentPages.length;
    showProgressBar(true);

    $.each(data.DocumentPages, function (index, documentPage) {

        updateProgressBar(progressBarSteps, index);

        var headerClass = $.validator.format('<h5 class="ui-widget-header">{0}</h5>', documentPage.Title);
        var image = $.validator.format('<img src="Handlers/ImageHandler.ashx?docid={0}&variantid={1}" alt="{2}"/>', documentPage.DocumentId, documentPage.ThumbVariantId, documentPage.Title);
        var imageUrl = $.validator.format('<a href="Handlers/ImageHandler.ashx?docid={0}&variantid={1}" title="Forstørr bilde" class="ui-icon ui-icon-zoomin">Forstørr bilde</a>', documentPage.DocumentId, documentPage.HoverVariantId, documentPage.Title);
        var listClass = $.validator.format('<li id="uncategorizedPage{0}" class="ui-widget-content ui-corner-tr">{1} {2} {3}</li>', documentPage.DocumentId, headerClass, image, imageUrl);

        listItems.push(listClass);
    });

    pub.UncategorizedPagesList.append(listItems.join(''));
    showProgressBar(false);
};


var updateProgressBar = function (progressBarStep, index) {

    //If this is true, the progressbar property is not set
    if (pub.Progressbar === "Progressbar") {
        return;
    }

    if (progressBarStep === 0) {
        return;
    }

    var progressBarValue = (100 / progressBarStep) * (index + 1);

    pub.Progressbar.progressbar({
        value: progressBarValue
    });
};

// Show/hide the progress bar and will also reset the progress bar
var showProgressBar = function (show) {

    if (show === true) {
        updateProgressBar(1, -1);
        pub.Progressbar.show();
    }
    else {
        pub.Progressbar.hide();
    }
};
```

The progress bar works. I know this because when I debug my javascript code I can see the progress bar is displayed and the value is increased. But to me is seems that the progress bar is hidden behind the rest of the ui when i run the code without debugging.

Do you have any tips and tricks to share with me?

Answer (score 0):

Try putting like this:

```
    <div id="splitDocumentProgressbar" style="width: 20%;"></div>
    <div id="mainCategorizerContainer">
        <div id="uncategorizedArea" class="uncategorized-area">
            <ul id="uncategorizedPagesList" class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-widget ui-helper-clearfix uncategorized-document-pages-list-area uncategorizedPages"></ul>
        </div>
        <div id="categorizedArea" class="categorized-area">
            <ul id="documentCategoryList" class="document-category-list-area ui-helper-reset"></ul>
            <ul id="categorizedDocumentPagesList" class="categorized-document-pages-list-area ui-helper-reset" ></ul>
        </div>
        <div id="splitDocumentDialog">
            <span id="splitDocumentDialogContent"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Your progressbar should appear above your code, if it doesn't you have the problem isolated in the progressbar.

Comment: This didn't work for me I'm afraid. I can't tell whether it's the progress bar or if it's some other issues. But thanks for the suggestion any way! I implemented a load-data-by-scrolling function instead. So now I load x number of list items when the user have scrolled to the bottom of the page instead of loading all list items when the user loads the page.